# Gradle-File warnings In IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I upgraded my IntelliJ IDEA installation from 2018.3 to 2019.1 and am now seeing errors in my `build.gradle` that were not there before. I suspect changed preferences but can not find any.

I am seeing two kinds of errors:

- Almost everything is underlined and the warning message popup says "No candidates found for method call plugins." or "No candidates found for method call buildscript."
- I use the Spring Boot plugin and import it on the first line. This is now red and the popup says "Cannot resolve symbol 'SpringBootPlugin'".

[image: Screenshot of IntelliJ error messages]

This worked fine in 2018.3. The gradle build works, i.e. running `./gradlew …:build` from the command line works and so does running gradle tasks from the IDE.

**Update**
I noticed that in "Project structure" the root module (this is a multi-module build) existed twice: once with the name in `settings.gradle` and once with the name of the directory the code is in. When changing the name in `settings.gradle` to the name of the directory, the duplicate entry in "Project structure" disappeared and the errors in `build.gradle` disappeared.

Comment: Have you tried to re-import project?

Comment: @IzbassarTolegen you mean with the "refresh" button in the Gradle tool window? Yes, that did not help.

Comment: Please check, that SpringBoot plugin's version is compatible with the current Idea version.

Answer (score 51):

Try re-importing the gradle project to do a "Gradle Sync" operation:

IntelliJ IDEA ➔ <kbd>Help</kbd> ➔ <kbd>Find Action</kbd> ➔ search for "import" or "reimport" ➔ Click on: **"Reimport All Gradle Projects"**

Edit: This has changed in August 2020: Click the <kbd>Gradle</kbd> toolbar/tab at the top-right to expand it, then locate a small refresh button at the top that looks like this  ➔ click **"Reload All Gradle Projects"** (it's the small refresh button).

Comment: This has changed to: Gradle (from the right toolbar) ➔ "Reload All Gradle Projects"

Comment: Yep, this thing works like a charm!

Answer (score 23):

Fixed with `File -> Invalidate caches / Restart`

`Help -> Find action... -> Reload All Gradle Projects` didn't work in Idea 2020.2 with me.

Comment: Same behavior for me. Invalidate/restart, then reloaded the Gradle project after indexing was finished. Now it's all tidy.

Answer (score 8):

The same occurred to me in Idea 2019.2 created the spring project from idea and by deleting the .iml file and .idea folder it was fixed

Comment: Same here in 2020.02 - Invalidate caches, Restart helped in my case

Answer (score 8):

You can do the same by clicking on the `Reload All Gradle Projects` icon in intelliJ 2020
[image: Reimport the projects again]

Comment: It bothers me that the arrow is pointing at the `+` icon

Answer (score 3):

I had problem with JaCoCo plugin. [Reload All Gradle Projects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C77CA.png) has resolved my issue. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I tried with Gradle settings, usually the issue is with gradle JVM

Preference - > Build, execution and deployment -> Gradle Update the JVM to the required version.

Comment: I don't seem to find the option, could you add more information? or maybe you could add a screenshot.  Thanks!

Comment: This fixed it for me too, thanks! In IntelliJ, it's under File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle.
In the 'Gradle JVM' section, select the same JDK version as the one you're using for your project.

Answer (score 0):

go to help -> actions and search for reload all gradle projects

Answer (score 0):

Go to:

File -> Invalidate caches / Restart

Help -> Find action... -> Reload All Gradle Projects : this does not  work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

in intelij IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3 (Community Edition)

Help -> Find action... -> Reload All Gradle Projects this steps work for me
Thanks

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).